# I want to create a Menu in shape of semi circle, with N number of menu-items

Tags: ios, swift, animation, menu

I want to create a menu like this,

[image: Menu image(with 4 items)].

But not getting perfect centre points for menu items(UIButton), 
I'm using `Stride(from:)` in `getCirclePoints()` to get CGPoint for menu-items with equal spacing from starting and ending angle.

`numberOfViews` variable contains the number of menu-items that i want to place.

If `numberOfViews = 5` then, the output will be

[image: Menu with 5 items].

Anyone is having better idea to create such dynamic menu, or help me out in this piece of code.

Thank you.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnMenu: UIButton!

    var numberOfViews: Int = 4
    var arrPoints: [CGPoint] = []
    var arrMenuItems = [UIButton]()

    var menuFrame: CGRect!
    var itemFrame: [CGRect] = []
    var isMenuOpen = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        prepareUI()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
}

extension ViewController {

    @IBAction func btnMenuTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        menu(open: isMenuOpen)
    }
}

extension ViewController {

    func prepareUI() {
        createMenuItems()
        storeFrame()
        btnMenu.makeRounded(0, isFullyRounded: true)
        menu(open: false, withDuration: 0.0001)
    }

    func createMenuItems() {
        arrPoints = getCirclePoints(centerPoint: btnMenu.center, radius: (self.view.bounds.width/CGFloat(numberOfViews) + 25), n: numberOfViews)
        for i in 0..<numberOfViews {
            drawMenuItem(for: i)
        }
    }

    func drawMenuItem(for index: Int) {
        var menuItem: UIButton
        let rect = CGRect(x: arrPoints[index].x, y: arrPoints[index].y, width: 50, height: 50)
        menuItem = UIButton(frame: rect)
        menuItem.makeRounded(0, isFullyRounded: true)
        menuItem.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor
        arrMenuItems.append(menuItem)
        view.addSubview(menuItem)
    }

    func getCirclePoints(centerPoint point: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, n: Int)->[CGPoint] {
        let result: [CGPoint] = stride(from: -168, to: 12, by: Double(180 / n)).map {
            let bearing = CGFloat($0) * .pi / 180
            let x = point.x + radius * cos(bearing)
            let y = point.y + radius * sin(bearing)
            return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        }
        return result
    }

    func storeFrame() {
        menuFrame = btnMenu.frame
    }

    func menu(open isOpen: Bool, withDuration duration: Double = 0.5) {
        if isOpen {
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.btnMenu)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                for element in self.arrMenuItems {
                    element.frame = self.menuFrame
                }
            }) { (completed) in
                self.isMenuOpen = !self.isMenuOpen
            }
        }else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                for (index, element) in self.arrMenuItems.enumerated() {
                    element.frame = CGRect(x: self.arrPoints[index].x, y: self.arrPoints[index].y, width: element.frame.width, height: element.frame.height)
                }
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }) { (completed) in
                self.isMenuOpen = !self.isMenuOpen
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UIButton {

    func makeRounded(_ cornerRadius: CGFloat, isFullyRounded: Bool) {
        if isFullyRounded {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 2
        }else {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }
}

// MARK:- Color extension
extension UIColor {

    // To get random color
    static var randomColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: .random(in: 0...1), green: .random(in: 0...1), blue: .random(in: 0...1), alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: can I suggest frameworks using it you can get appropriate output with animations ...

Comment: Sure, you can suggest. But @ShivamParmar I want to learn such basic things so in future i won't get stuck.

Comment: Yes @shraddha11, but apart from [fan-menu](https://github.com/exyte/fan-menu/).

Comment: @PratikGhadia From a learning perspective, third-party libraries are pretty useful too! Yes, they get your job done but, you could also explore how it's done, based on their code. Even if you get it done yourself, their approach towards it could be different (and perhaps more efficient) You don't necessarily have to import them to your project for this. If it's a recognised library, they'd have a demo project with simple implementation. Utilise that project! I'd suggest you to get started based on this, try adding your touches, and get back if you face issues

Answer (score 2):

you can use [fan-menu](https://github.com/exyte/fan-menu) Library for semi circle menu

Comment: Thank you @karan, I already gone through this library. But I want to learn from scratch, and from basics.

Answer (score 0):

For a given position of the showMenu button which shows/collapse menu options on tap.

Assume we have an circle around the showMenu button, where we have to display menu options on the circumference of the circle.
Given position of showMenu button : (cx,xy) is known

get the position of the menu options using formula below:

```
x = cx + r * cos(a) 
y = cy + r * sin(a)
```

where r is the radius of circle, (cx,cy) the centre of showMenu, and the angle = (90)/numberofMenu

For a given set of points derived from formula for each menu buttons, add your Menu button options and animate accordingly.